# No matter what I researched and did I can't connect to my MySQL server

Tags: mysql, firewall, remote

Ubuntu installed MySQL for me through LAMP. When I connect with SSH I can login with the root user but not the user i created myself. When I use HeidiSQL I can't login with anything. I ran these commands

```
mysql -u root -p
CREATE DATABASE something;
GRANT ALL ON something.* TO something@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; 
flush privileges;
sudo service mysql restart
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i p3p1 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

EDIT: my.conf : http://pastebin.com/ZwhJ6buN

Comment: I noticed you have set a plain-text password. Are you sure your system is not set up expecting to receive a md5 hashed password instead? If I remember correctly the default is to expect usage of the PASSWORD() fuction.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/assigning-passwords.html explains some of the inner workings of using passwords and why your connection might be denied by the server when you assign plain-text passwords.

Comment: I ran this command logged in as root mysql user 'set password for 'something'@'%' = PASSWORD('password');'
'flush privileges;'
'sudo service mysql restart '
But it still doesnt let me in over SSH

Comment: Do you get an error message or any feedback when you try to connect? If so, please include it to the question. Also check http://chxo.com/be2/20040511_5667.html for a demo ssl setup for mysql.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I had a busy weekend. I get this error message: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'something'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Answer (score 1):

I got it fixed. Almost smacked myself for not thinking about this :)

I had to add a NAT rule to my router with port 3306 and the servers local IP address